# FirstOrDefault() type error on return?

Tags: wpf, wcf, entity-framework, ria

A RIA Domain service has this method...

```
public virtual CmsDealer GetCmsDealer(string id)
{
    return this.Context.CmsDealerSet.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

The Wcf service has this...

```
public CmsDealer GetDealer(string id)
{
    return domainservice.GetCmsDealer(id);
}
```

When called with a nonexistent Id, the GetCmsDealer() call barfs with an exception about

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'RIAServicesLibrary.Web.Models.CmsDealer[]'.

It was my impression that it would simply retun a null, that I could test for later. Yet somehow that isn't happening. All the examples I find show something like this working fine.

Any insight helpful, I am a little baffled and a bit of a newb about EF, RIA and Wcf.

**Updated:** The problem is that I need to track the failure all the way dowwn to Wcf so that the application that ultimately calls GetDealer can find out that there was no solution. Ideally, I need to do that without leaving uncaught exceptions around :)

A try / catch solution inside GetCmsDealer will allow me to detect the failure, but there is still no way to rerutn a "Empty" CmsDealer object without faking a number of contraints (it seems entity is picky about it).

So I can try / catch in GetDealer as well, but I still dont have a valid CmsDealer object to return.

Thanks!

**UPDATED**

For those who were wondering how it played out, the final routine looked like this...

```
public virtual IQueryable<CmsDealer> GetCmsDealerSetOrEmpty(string id)
{
    return this.Context.CmsDealerSet
        .Include("CmsItemState")
        .Where(p => p.Id == id)
        ;
}
```

The Wcf wrapper is now back to being a simple pass through. On the client I check the Count() of the result, if it is 0 then I can knwo there was no record, if it's 1 then a simple First() gets me the record.

I am willing to bet there is a better way.

Comment: Where are you encountering that error?

Comment: I am getting the error during runtime debugging in the Wcf service at the return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also modify the Domain service to do a select instead so that you will get an IEnumerable (which has a count if I'm not mistaken) that you can test in your WCF service. So you would modify this to be something like:
public virtual IEnumerable GetDealer(string id){
   return this.Context.CmsDealerSet.Select(p => p.Id == id);
}

Then in the WCF Service you can do:
public CmsDealer GetDealer(string id)
{
    var x = domainservice.GetCmsDealer(id);
    if(x.Count() == 0)
    { 
        // oops, nothing to see here
    } else {
        // have a live on here
    }
}

Comment: Ok, thats just clever :)

Thanks!

Comment: In the end, that is what I did.

     public virtual IQueryable<CmsDealer> GetCmsDealerSetOrEmpty(string id)
  {
       return this.Context.CmsDealerSet
           .Include("CmsItemState")
           .Where(p => p.Id == id)
           ;
  }

I pass that out through wcf and check the count on the client. Still, it feels ugly :)

Comment: Now, that "Select" needs to be a Where in liams answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good opportunity for the [Null Object Pattern](http://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jwalker/nullObjPattern/) For an example of it think of Double.NaN as a default value.

Changing the Domain service function as follows

```
public virtual CmsDealer GetCmsDealer(string id)
{
  return this.Context.CmsDealerSet.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id)??
    CmsDealer.NullValue;
}
```

Allows you to have a valid value in the WCF service and perform the check on the client

Comment: Wow, if that works that will just be AWESOME. I will check it out later and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I checked the link. That pattern looks good, I'll try and build it into the next project.

Answer (score 0):

FirstOrDefault will return Null if no matching records are found. I suspect that your service is having an issue with the null return. I would recommend altering this to throw an exception if no matches are found and catch the exception on your client.

Jim

Comment: The problem is when I have to jump down the wire to the wcf client. I could construct an empty CmsDealer object I suppose and pass that down, then test for it on the far side.